# onChange event CKeditor with dynamically created CKeditors using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am having difficulties applying the onChange event on my CKeditors.

I am creating the editors dynamically using the following code:

```
 $('.dashboard_container').on('click', 'p.content, h1.content, h2.content, h3.content, h4.content, h5.content, strong.content, cite.content', function(){
    CKeditor = $(this).ckeditor({ customConfig: '/dist/ckeditor/custom_config.js',
     });

    CKeditor.on('change', function(){
        console.log('change');
    })
});
```

As you can see I also tried to apply the onChange event on the newly created CKeditor object, but it does not seems to work.

I used this example: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/saveajax.html and tried to rewrite the example code to be applied dynamically, but it does not trigger anything. What am I doing wrong?

---

Example code from the CKeditor website below:

```
(function () {
        var changesCount = 0;
        var editor2 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
            removePlugins: 'sourcearea'

        } );
        editor2.on( 'change', function ( ev ) {
            changesCount++;
            document.getElementById( 'content2' ).style.display = '';
            document.getElementById( 'changes' ).innerHTML = changesCount.toString();
            document.getElementById( 'editorcontent2' ).innerHTML = editor2.getData();
        } );
    })();
```

### EDIT

Added a (not) working example: https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/gcasv2xw/4/

Comment: did you try the onkeypress event

Comment: No, the onkeypress event is not the one I am looking for. I am trying to get a trigger for changing the content with a button (setting) of the CKeditor.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't declare `CKeditor` globally. Secondly, you are binding change event on each click, nesting events is bad practice. Now can you provide MCVE replicating your issue?

Comment: True, and true. But on click, the editor has to appear. And I firstly want to see the change event work.
I am not sure I can create an MCVE, because I am using the jquery.js adapter from CKeditor, and it does not seem to be available anywhere online...